# category name is not showing at products index

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m getting products at products index page and I wants to show the name of category under which the product is, so only category id is showing but category name is not showing

blade file:

```html
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.product.show', $product->id) }}" style="color: #37333d;">
            {{ ucwords($product->product_name) }}
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>{{ $product->product_slug }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->category_id }}{{ $product->category_name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

productcontroller:

````php
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('admin.product.index', compact('products'));
}


product.php

      class Product extends Model
      {
      protected $fillable = [
     'product_name', 'product_description', 'product_image', 'category_id', 'product_code', 'product_price', 'product_status', 'product_slug'
    ];

        public function category()
        {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
        }
      }```

category model:

       class Category extends Model
       {
          protected $fillable = [
         'category_name', 'category_description', 'category_slug', 'category_image'
       ];

         public function products()
         {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
         }
      }
````

Comment: can you please dd($product)?

Comment: Can you also provide your `Product` model and relation with `Category`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your controller change:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::with('category')->get();
    return view('admin.product.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Then in your view you are be able to do:

```
<td>{{ $product->category_id }}{{ $product->category->category_name }}</td>
```

If you have any errors with this solution provide it here.

Good luck!

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()

Comment: Change it to `get()`. I will update my answer. Did work now? @n00t

Answer (score 1):

```
1. check your Product.php is their category_name exit or not

2.  where are from category name which model product or category.
  if in category you should get relationship between category and product 


if category name from category model
your code is

public function index()
{
    $products = Product::with('category')->get();
    return view('admin.product.index', compact('products'));
}

make relationship one to one between product & category
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()

Comment: use  get() instead of all()

Answer (score 0):

1- Create in your Product model the relationship

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

2- In your Blade file call this relantionship in order to get the name of the category:

```
<td>{{ $product->category_id }}{{ $product->category->name }}</td>
```

Comment: You are calling the category name using     $product->category_name. Try using $product->category->name